# Objective-C How can I detect multitouch that come from many subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, multi-touch

Objective-C

Suppose I have main view name which have three subviews A, B, and C.

A is scrollView. Both B and C are image view.

I need to detect multitouch on the main view. For example, if you use two fingers touch at screen the alert box will show.

If the two fingers is touch at the same subviews it will be OK.

But if one finger touch at view B and another touch at view C there will be a problem because the main view receive 2 sequential touch not multitouch.

I wonder if there is a solution for this problem?

Thank you for every answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this -

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(multiTap:)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.yourView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];
```

You could implement `multiTap` which handles this event. But optentially, what you are trying to do could be confusing to the user. Anyway that's your call. Technologically this is possible...

Comment: This is Tap Gesture Recognizer for one view. If I tap on 2 subview how can I know.

Comment: Add a handler for that view too... If you have an insane number of views then you might want to rethink your approach

Comment: Yes you can add gesture recognizer for many subviews, but it still send sequential single touch event not multitouch event

Answer (score 0):

In theory, one possible solution path to explore is adding a transparent glass view above all, as a subview to the main view, so it would be a sibling of views A,B,C that would receive all taps. Attach a UITapGestureRecognizer and set a UIGestureRecognizerDelegate on all subviews, to mutually exclude the recognition of gestures in views D, and A at the same time, with method shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer.

In practice, imho best solution is not to face this problem at all, and instead of trying to recognize multi finger taps that may fall on different subviews, go for pinch & zoom recognition (UIPinchGestureRecognizer) as it won't collide with regular UITapGestureRecognizers, and you won't have this problem.